# Crowdsourcing translation for mobile developers?

Tags: localization, mobile, translation

I am developing applications for mobile phones with different operating systems (Android, Symbian, iPhone). Applications are sold internationally so they need to be translated to different languages in addition to english version.

I assume most mobile developers do the translations using some paid external service each time. This approach does not look very cost-effective to me. Would it make sense to have a website where simple translations would be done using crowdsourcing (other developers)? Most strings in mobile applications are very simple and short, for example "OK, "Cancel", "Are you sure?", "Please enter your password". Also the same strings are used in hundreds of applications. Instead of paying for translating all strings, developers could save money by only buying their difficult application specific translations.

Does anyone agree with this idea? I have seen many opensource projects doing the translations succesfully using volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft allows you to view their terminology database: https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Default.aspx

That covers about 90 languages and will get you the things you mention such as common button captions, etc.

The problem you are facing after that is to try to get only the strings translated that you want.  Most translators are going to charge you a minimum number of words.  And they are going to want the entire resource file (regardless if you translated them yourself or not).  Makes sense because localizing a product means that they need to have the whole picture to ensure consistency, etc.  Professional translators will probably not charge you for what they call 100% matches.

I would never ever trust the translation of my product to crowd sourcing.  Ever.  You get what you pay for.  Besides, just because you speak a language natively doesn't mean that you can write well, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I just found solution for me. Many users find this question in Google so I think my post must be helpful:

This is solution for us: **[crowdin.com](https://crowdin.com/)** - agile localization solution for tech companies

Answer (score 0):

How do you check the crowd sourcing translation results for accuracy and quality? In a famous and documented occurrence recently the phrase "No lorries by this route please use the main road" was translated into "We are out of the office until Monday please contact us again then" and turned into road signs that were erected.

Crowd sourcing translation has been used and FaceBook is probably the largest company i know of that tried/used it. I have not tracked their progress but you could investigate it to see it's success or otherwise. Their method of quality checking was to get other people using the translations to vote for the one they preferred, so this was a case of crowd sourcing quality control. At this point the proposal that a camel is a horse designed by a committee jumps unbidden into my mind.

Translation, in spite of all the machine pumped into it, is still more of an art than a science. To translate correctly you need to have a native speaker translating from another language into their own. So for English to German you need a native German speaker who can speak English very well to do it. Within the profession very, very few translators will translate to a language in which they are non native. The reasons for this are many but boil down to the colloquial nature of language.

To be positive you could look at how Facebook fared and follow that route. Another route would be to approach not translators, but a translation agency, there are quite a number of these. Present them with the whole corpus you want translating in the original English and get them to quote you for the whole job. This would mean someone else manhging the job and the quality and they may have shortcuts, especially if the translations are to fairly standard "computerese" type phrases. i.e.'Home', 'Back', 'Next', 'Click here' etc.